# While loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to crop an image for `n` times.
I opened `figure(1)` and croped the image.
After croping the image `I` and getting `I2`, I want to repeat this process until the user doesn't hit `Enter`.

```
RECT=[];    
hfig1=figure(1);    
while **[ User have not enterd Enter key]**    
    I = imread('coins.png');   
    [I2,rect] = imcrop(I);    
    hfig=figure(2);    
    imshow(I2) 
    close(hfig)    
    RECT=[RECT;rect];
end    
close(hfig1);
```

How do I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestrood correctly your question you should be fine with:

```
hist=[];    
original=imread('stackoverflow.png');
figo=figure;
imshow(original);
again='yes';
figc=figure;
while again    
    [cropped,rect]=imcrop(original);        
    imshow(cropped);
    original=cropped;
    hist=[hist;rect];
    again=input('Do you want more? [N]: ', 's');
end
```

Comment: I don't want to close my main window (figure1). Secondly, this loop is never ending.

Comment: The loop ends when user types enters when prompted but of course you could tweak this by modifying the condition used to test `again`.